# how to write pl/sql named programme for this

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a table `M_PARAMETER` which has a column `MMRUN`.

When this `MMRUN='Y'` then the User can not modify any transaction in the app's front end. When `MMRUN='N'` then the User can do the modification.

`emp`,`dept`,`salgrade` table do not modify `users` when `MMRUN='Y'`

Comment: ? Need more details before we can be helpful here. Not really sure what you're trying to achieve, short of limiting a person's ability to change rows (which, I guess, you could use triggers to accomplish).

Comment: Is there an actual question here? I don't think so, I edited for some reasonable amount of clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a global system context to do this.  See here [Oracle context](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/create_context.html)

The user logs on, your stored procedure determines the value of MMRun for that user and the context is set for this session.
Then your triggers or insert/update/delete triggers or procedures refer to the context for permission to edit.

Really though this sounds like something that will require a more fine grained permission structure in the future. I've never seen something simple like can modify/cannot modify stay simple. Usually you are asked to provide variations on this in the future. There are  open source PL/SQL  packages available which can be adapted to do this.